# What's the difference between confit and fondant potato?

Tags: potatoes, fondant, confit

So they both seem to always require relatively long cooking in some kind of liquid containing fat. The only difference I seem to be able to find is the shaping of the potato and colouring of it by frying of the fondant potato.

Is this correct? Is this the only difference?

I'd also like it if someone can provide a generic definition of both!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Confit and fondant potatoes have different cooking methods.

Fondant potatoes are fried with oil on one side and with butter on the orher side, and then boiled in stock.

Confit potatoes are deep fried at low temperature.

Answer (score 2):

From my understanding the French word Confit means a preserving method. Confit potatoes are preserved in duck fat overnight and then deep fried to a crispy outside texture. Very different from fondant potatoes that are seared on the outside and then simmered in chicken broth and butter.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, the main difference is that fondant has a **different shape** and the **crisp top and bottom** verses the **evenly cooked** and **consistant texture** to confit. Also **typically** confit is slightly **more seasoned**.